# Is it ok to use sterile eye drops every day

Tags: eye, allergy, practice-of-medicine

I have very allergic eyes that redden up very quickly even without rubbing. When it becomes too much I see the doctor and take some eye drops for a month. But the allergy keeps on coming back.

A few years back I used to use this eye drops called, [Clearine](https://www.medidart.com/products/CLEARINE-EYE-DROPS-10ML1.html). That used to solve my problems right away. Now theses have been discontinued. Now I went to the medical store and asked the pharmaceutical expert there and he suggested some sterile eye drops. Is it ok to use them on daily or a bidaily basis?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by sterile eye drops? Most eye drops are sterile formulations so you do not introduce bacteria or pyrogens into your eyes.

Regardless, I looked into the product Clearine and found that the active ingredient is naphazoline. There are still many over the counter eye drop products that contain naphazoline so you might consider trying one of those.
[Visine-A is one example](https://www.visine.com/product-visine-a-allergy-eye-drops)

If those are not strong enough there are some prescription only naphazoline eye drops that have a higher concentration that you could discuss with your doctor.